# Integrate Aloha Editor into a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to throw together a prototype Rails app with the Aloha Editor to demonstrate at work, since that editor appears it will resolve some of the frustrations our content editors are having with our current (Drupal-based) WYSIWYG editing situation on our site.   (Aloha integration with Drupal is still in early alpha, and it makes our site essentially unavailable.)

The problem is that there are at least three github projects named `/aloha.rails/`, and it's unclear which is the best starting point.  Since this is basically skunkworks until management sees it can solve our problems and approves further work, I can't spend a lot of time on one, only to discover I should have used a different one.  Is there any that is the current *de facto* standard?

Here are the three projects:

- https://github.com/tylergannon/aloha_rails
- https://github.com/Skalar/aloha-rails
- https://github.com/locomotivecms/aloha-rails

There is no mention of any of these being a fork of another.

Comment: Your best bet would be to clone the repo on github and build off that. I have faced many issues with zip file on their site. Tried to use it a year ago.. Great concept though

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal: yes, but *which* repo.  That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: The official Aloha repo which isn't Rails related. Those repo's you listed are all garbage, I've tried them. I think part of the reason is because Aloha has an incredibly contrived setup which is difficult to rollout in a ruby gem; such a shame because the tool itself is amazing but a real pain in the ass to actually implement.

Comment: I actually think the Mercury Editor is *much* nicer, but it's Ruby-only, so I can't jam it into a Drupal app/site.